# The method setText(String) is undefined for the type ListView

Tags: android, string, listview, settext

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId()==R.id.save ) {
        String text = mtextInput.getText().toString();
        mtextOutput.setText(text + "\n" + mtextInput.getText().toString());
```

Any thoughts? Get error on .setText - "The method setText(String) is undefined for the type ListView"

Comment: You are referring the **ListView** (v) in the onClick method. And ListViews **don't have the setText method**. Their internal controls might have it (if they are, for instance, TextViews).

Comment: The error message is about as explanatory as you can get. ListView does not have a method `setText(String)`.

Comment: Okey, thanks
I want to have a list with things the user add. Spotify playlist is a good example. I'm not doing anything with Music but you get the Point. I Think ListView works fine? If so, any tutorial or something that can get it to work insteed of .setText?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you first need to learn about the different Android UI elements. You clearly don't know what a `ListView` or a `TextView` are. You could start [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html) in the docs to learn about general UI elements and patterns. From there, go to the [samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/index.html) that are included in the SDK - especially check the [UI samples](http://developer.android.com/samples/ui.html). Then use google to find more examples of `ListViews` if you wanna use that. [This](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html) looks like a good one.

Comment: Looked at all the links, the problem is that i want to have a textinput and what i write there and press add will be added into the ListView, cant find any tutorial on that. Just how you write your specific Word into the ListView

Comment: Either use a custom adapter, and add one more row at the end manually that contains the input box, use a footer for it or just add the input box below the listview.